# default page in pnp4nagios

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I am using pnp4nagios along with the nagios.

Everything seems to be integrated properly - I have "extra action" icons close to every host and service which links to pnp4nagios graph.

However, when I am going to the https://x.x.x.x/pnp4nagios/ it always change the url to the:

```
https://x.x.x.x/pnp4nagios/graph?host=webhost01
```

How Can I turn off this behaviour?

I would like to see on /pnp4nagios/ collected graphs from all servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pages](http://docs.pnp4nagios.org/pnp-0.6/pages) and/or [Special templates](http://docs.pnp4nagios.org/pnp-0.6/tpl_special) is what you're looking for.

But I think you probably only want to collect all the graphs of ONE service for all servers, e.g. CPU Load.

Here's an example to collect the MySQL_uptime graphs on `MySQL_Master_6.47` and `datawarehouse1`:

**`/usr/local/pnp4nagios/etc/pages/mysql_uptime.cfg`**:

```
define  page  {
    use_regex 0
    page_name MySQL Uptime
}

define graph {
    host_name       MySQL_Master_6.47,datawarehouse1
    service_desc    MySQL_uptime
    source          0
}
```

Access to http://yourdomain.com/pnp4nagios/page, you'll see something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write a custom script to collect and display all the pnp4nagios graphs for all servers.  It isn't part of the default functionality (because that would be a huge number of graphs on any reasonably sized setup).